# Encrypt data. Create 5 keys. Just 3 keys are needed for decryption

Tags: encryption, keys, secret-sharing, decryption

I would like to encrypt some data and create 5 keys. These keys are stored in different places. If I want to decrypt the data I just need 3 of these 5 keys.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See [secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing)

Comment: ...and the [tag:secret-sharing] tag on this site.

Comment: FYI, there is an intrinsic limitation to secret-sharing: if you ever want to _use_ the secret then you have to assemble the shares in one place, and whoever assembles the shares to recover the secret then has unilateral power to do whatever the secret enables them to do.  If, for example, the secret is a _signing key_ that lets you sign an authorization to (say) transfer your money somewhere, then you may be better off using a _threshold signature scheme_ instead of secret-sharing so that it takes joint participation of the signers but there is _never_ a single secret assembled in one place.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: Indeed. For the OP's task as described, however, it seems perfectly suited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.  And it generalizes easily to requiring any $k$ out of $n$ keys, not just 3 out of 5:

1. Generate a random key for some symmetric encryption scheme (say, [AES-SIV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5297)).
2. Encrypt your data with that random key.
3. Use a *threshold secret sharing scheme* such as [Shamir's secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) to split the random key into $n$ shares, such that any $k$ of them are needed to reconstruct the key.

You can use those $n$ shares directly as the $n$ "keys" to be stored in different places.  However, if you'd instead prefer to use $n$ *pre-existing* keys, you'll need one more step:

4. Encrypt each share with one of the $n$ keys (using whatever encryption scheme you prefer, either symmetric or asymmetric) and store the encrypted shares alongside the encrypted data from step 2.

To decrypt the data, do the same in reverse: first decrypt at least $k$ of the shares (if needed), then reconstruct the random key from those shares, and finally decrypt the data using the random key.

Shamir's secret sharing is [unconditionally secure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information-theoretic_security), so the whole scheme is as secure as the encryption schemes you use in steps 2 and (optionally) 4.